# MySQL Special symbols

Tags: mysql, special-characters, symbols

Is it possible to insert a special symbol like a checkmark or a filled circle into a MySQL table and then retrieve it through a SELECT?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you clarify what issue you are facing?

Comment: I have my <input type="checbox"> with a value="MySpecialCharacter(like a checkmark), but when I insert it, it writes something like &403æ. Something like that. Im interested in knowing what the input line is like, and the PHP

Comment: are you really sure that's a good idea? Wouldn't it be much easier to store a `0` / `1` value in the database, and to output the checkmark later when you *show* the data?

Comment: That will be easier yes - I am parsing it through a json script into a iphone application. Here is where I dont know how to change the shown data, other than what is store in the column of the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can works with unicode encode data, you have several [checkmarks in unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick_%28check_mark%29):

```
U+2713 ✓ check mark
U+2714 ✔ heavy check mark
U+2610 ☐ ballot box
U+2611 ☑ ballot box with check
```

Comment: So where do I type in the U+2714? In the value of the input line?

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. First convert your table to utf8mb4:

```
ALTER TABLE your_database_name.your_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
```